# Can I bring an old artillery shell on a plane?

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, europe

I have been travelling in Europe, and picked up an old artillery shell that the seller told me was empty. When I went to inspect it at home, I removed the projectile and found that the shell is in fact empty, but that the projectile has not been drilled. For more context, this is very likely a 25mm Hotchkiss anti-tank or anti-air artillery shell that has a timed fuse head. While the powder in the head is inert, I am not sure if I can bring it on the plane(in checked baggage or carry-on) back with me to the US.

Does anyone know whether this would be allowed both on the plane or through customs? I am flying American Airlines out of France into the US

Comment: You're referring to customs (which checks things entering the country, mostly to ensure taxes are paid, and prohibited items are not imported and is usually done at the airport where you will be entering the US) and TSA (which is in charge of security on flights departing from the US and to a lesser extent to the US). Which one do you actually want to know about? Also, if you're departing from Europe, local regulations would probably be relevant.

Comment: I guess I'm referring to both customs and the local security, I forgot that TSA only checks outbound flights. I will fix the post

Comment: Related: [Can I bring empty bullet shell casings (spent ammo) in checked luggage on an international flight?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/50916/can-i-bring-empty-bullet-shell-casings-spent-ammo-in-checked-luggage-on-an-int) and [American tourist allegedly tries to take 'souvenir' WWI artillery shell on plane](https://www.foxnews.com/travel/american-tourist-allegedly-tries-to-take-souvenir-wwi-artillery-shell-on-plane).

Comment: Wait a second, " the powder in the head is inert " -- are you asking whether you can bring _gunpowder_ on a plane?? I know it's not black powder but still.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I bring empty bullet shell casings (spent ammo) in checked luggage on an international flight?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/50916/can-i-bring-empty-bullet-shell-casings-spent-ammo-in-checked-luggage-on-an-int)